# How to add tags or baggage with spring-cloud starter?

Tags: spring, opentracing, jaeger

I am trying to add a tag or baggage to an OpenTracing trace. I am creating the tracer via @Beans but can not figure out how to reference the active span when using the autoconfiguration that comes with cloud-starter.

Using this dependency

```
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.4</version>
```

I tried this

```
    tracer.activeSpan().setBaggageItem("baggage", "baggage");
```

And this

```
    scope.span().setBaggageItem("baggage", "baggage");
```

Both result in NPE. Even trying to log the span or tracer object gives me an NPE so seems I do not have to right pattern for interacting with it.

Here is how the tracer is getting setup.

```
    @Bean
    public io.opentracing.Tracer jaegerTracer() {
        SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig = SamplerConfiguration.fromEnv().withType("const").withParam(1);
        SenderConfiguration senderConfig = SenderConfiguration.fromEnv().withEndpoint("http://jaeger:14268/api/traces");
        ReporterConfiguration reporterConfig = ReporterConfiguration.fromEnv().withLogSpans(true).withSender(senderConfig);
        Configuration config = new Configuration("eclipse-hawkular").withSampler(samplerConfig).withReporter(reporterConfig);
        return config.getTracer();
    }
```

More info...

Looking at the [opentracing-spring-web-contrib code](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/0ac36c39c5a6786a3537425ea7c1c8065c03bd32/opentracing-spring-web/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/client/RestTemplateSpanDecorator.java) where the span decorator is defined which is where I am getting the default spans and associated tags from. But how to add custom tag/baggage if executing the restTemplate is what triggers the intercept that starts the active span? I assume I should not be interacting with the spanDecorator directly.

And more info...

Also tried to add baggage when using [opentracing-contrib-okhttp](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-okhttp). Tracing worked great but cannot figure out how to add bagged when using the interceptor based auto tracers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can now add baggage with this single line.

```
TracerResolver.resolveTracer().activeSpan().setBaggageItem("baggage", "adding baggage");
```

In the course of working on this also started using Spring 2.0.9.RELEASE and a single dependency for OpenTracing which uses the 0.32 version of the Jaeger tracer.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The `resolveTracer` operation is relatively expensive. Take a look at the GlobalTracer: you can use it in your `jaegerTracer` method, wrapping the actual tracer. Then, in the code you can just use `GlobalTracer.get().activeSpan()...`. It should though be possible to inject a Tracer into your bean, though. If it's not working, I recommend opening an issue against the `opentracing-spring` repo.